# Why can't I instantiate an object in a class?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, sfml

I have these three codes:

```
#pragma once

class Rect
{
private:
    int m_Thing;
public:
    Rect(int thing)
    {
        m_Thing = thing;
    }

    void create(int thing)
    {
        m_Thing = thing;
    }
};
```

```
#pragma once
#include "Rect.h"

class Brick
{
private:
    Rect floatRect;
public:
    Brick()
    {
        floatRect.create(28);
    }
};
```

```
#include "mre.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Brick brick;
}
```

For some reason, I get an error that says I need a default constructor. I make one, and then I get an unresolved external symbol error on the Rect object. That's where I'm stuck. How can I instantiate it?

Comment: The compiler is correct, by declaring a non default constructor, the default constructor is deleted (for Rect). And your implicitly declared constructor for Brick tries to call the default constructor for Rect.

Comment: Also note : when you have a constructor with one argument, make it `explicit`. So `explicit Rect(int value)`

Comment: Before the function body of the `Brick` constructor is called, all members are constructed. Since you don't explicitly construct (or initialize) the `floatRect` member it will be default constructed. And your `Rect` class doesn't have a default constructor. You need to add an *initializer-list* to the `Brick` constructor instead: `Brick() : floatRect(28) { /* Empty constructor body */ }`

Comment: For documentation on constructors see [default constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) and pay attention to : *Deleted implicitly-declared default constructorr*

Comment: The `create` function makes it look like you're missing the point of constructors.

Comment: Oh I see, that part was actually part of my attempt at a solution. I was going to instantiate the Rect and then use create to reset the parameters inside of an update function (for a game). (this is just an mre of a bigger code.)

Comment: the constructor sets everything at creation, so I used create to reset it.

Comment: @ElijahCampbell Then "create" is a terrible name. (And it is completely irrelevant to a [mcve].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call an default constructor of a class, all of its members are default constructed unless specified some other way. If we wanted to write what happens explicitly in the call of `Brick()`, it would look like this.

```
Brick() : floatRect()
{
    floatRect.create(28);
}
```

Here we can see that in the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) it attempts to call the default constructor of `Rect`, which is implicitly deleted because you have  a user-defined constructor. If you want to create `Rect`, you can do the following.

```
Brick() : floatRect(28)
{
    
}
```

The member initialized field is purposely for initializing or passing arguments to the constructors of members.